# How do I create a custom payment module on Prestashop without a credit card?

Tags: prestashop, purchase-order

This is the first time I've asked a question on here so I'm sure I'll be off on the question I'm trying to ask, but here's what I'm dealing with:

I'm using prestashop on my website that will only accept payment from people within our Bartering service group. So the only information needed for them to place an order is their contact information and their personal ID from the Bartering group so that we can accept the order and make sure they apply that. So I want to change the checkout to not actually charge anything, but rather send an email to the sales team and to the customer containing the product they ordered and their personal information. I've already done a couple of overrides with prestashop, but I haven't been able to find what all modules/classes need overridden for this particular issue.

Any advice even a basic list of what modules and classes to look at would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Thanks for the advice folks. I think the module should be pretty straight forward. It does not have to charge any balance or anything, just send an email with the order details and customer info to both us and the customer.

Comment: I would create a new payment module with a form with the needed fields and then send the information in the `hookNewOrder`

Comment: Look at the "cheque" payment module. Do not override. Just create a new module by making a copy of this one and modify it for your needs. If you want more help, you'll have to be more specific and edit your question to show us what does not work.

Comment: its very simple, you dont go with override, go to prestashop online module generator site and generate a pyment module. You will get a default payment module which will complete the payment by clicking the button. You can modfiy the code and do your logic.